# Notice : Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I got

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference this error while I upload the picture in php can you anyone tell me how to solve this. Below is my code where the error is come.

```
$exten = end((explode(".", $name))); 
$imagename1=$sname."-".$rno.".".$exten;
```